# Why is my code not executing?

Tags: c

Currently learning C - and I have no clue where I'm going wrong in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char alphabet[20];
    int i;

    for (int i = 0; i > 20; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter in a letter:\n");
        scanf("%s", alphabet[i]);
        if (alphabet[i] == alphabet[i+1])
        {
            printf("Duplicate Letters");
        };
    return 0;
    }

}
```

The program that I am asked to make for class — I'm required to create a 1D array, add validation for alphabetical letters and duplicate letters, as well as creating a function for sorting the letters and specifying the number of times each letter was put in.

As much as I've been able to attempt coding is:

- Create a 1D array to read 20 alphabetical letters
- Add validation for duplicate letters and printf 'Duplicate Letters'
  but every time I try, the program terminates at 'Enter in a letter:' or it won't execute.

Where did I go wrong?

For background: I work mainly on Windows 7 because that's what the school has — using MinGW as my compiler — but for working at home I use MacOS using Terminal as the compiler.

Comment: "Terminal" is not a compiler. Nor is MinGW.

Comment: When you fix the loop control, you'll be comparing a letter you read with an as yet ununinitialized entry in the array — well, it depends on exactly what you type, but you are reading strings and then comparing single characters.  And if your compiler isn't complaining about the `scanf()` call, you need to turn on the compiler warnings, or get a better compiler.

Comment: Additonally, `return 0;` goes outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: `scanf("%s", alphabet[i]);` -> `scanf("%c", alphabet[i]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i > 20; i++)
```

You're telling the computer here to initialize `i` to 0, and then, while `i` is greater than 20, do the loop. However, since `i` starts at 0, it will never be greater than 20.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
```

And, yes, as comments have pointed out, your use of scanf is incorrect. Lacking a better C reference for it, check out http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ for descriptions of its arguments.

Comment: How about `scanf("%s", alphabet[i]);`? See anything wrong with that?